# android- how to change the color of canvas in a view?

Tags: android, android-canvas

I have written a customized `View` which draws a circle(it's `onDraw` function has been overridden to do that).

Now how doI change the color of my circle, from code?(from the `Activity` function  which is going to show that circle)

Comment: you could have a setter to change the paint's color you are using to draw the circle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make a setCircleColor to change the color of the circle and call invalidate that will call the View onDraw method.
You can also check for [invalidate(Drawable drawable)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/Drawable.Callback.html#invalidateDrawable(android.graphics.drawable.Drawable)).

```
public class MyCustomView extends View {

    MyCustomView myView; 

    private Paint myCircle;
    public MyCustomView(Context context){
        super(context);
        initView();
    }

    private void initView(){
        myView = this; 

        myCircle = new Paint();
        myCircle.setColor(0xa300ff00);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        drawCircle(canvas);
    }

    private void drawCircle(Canvas canvas){
        canvas.drawCircle(canvas.getWidth()/2, canvas.getHeight()/2, 10, myCircle);
    }

    public void setCircleColor(int color){
        myCircle.setColor(color);
        myView.invalidate();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks!! This helped me tremendously.